# swap last 2 string of columns seperated by delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I hava a dataframe. I want to swap last 2 string of columns seperated by "_" if the 2nd last string is "pi"

Dataframe has columns such as:

```
     abc_rte        abc_rte_log     abc_rte_log_pi1     abc_rte_pi1_log     xyz_pnct_pi2_log
```

Desired column names:

```
      abc_rte       abc_rte_log     abc_rte_log_pi1     abc_rte_log_pi1     xyz_pnct_log_pi2
```

What i tried so far:

```
        for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
          if str(df.columns[i].split('_')[-2] == 'pi':
            df.columns[i].split('_')[-2] = str(df.columns[i].split('_')[-1])
```

Answer (score 5):

#### `Index.str.replace`

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(pi\d*)_([^_]+)$', r'\2_\1')
```

---

```
>>> df.columns

Index(['abc_rte', 'abc_rte_log', 'abc_rte_log_pi1', 'abc_rte_log_pi1',
       'xyz_pnct_log_pi2'],
      dtype='object')
```

**Regex details:**

- `(pi\d*)` : First capturing group

  - `pi` : Matches the characters `pi` literally
  - `\d*` : Matches a digit between zero or more times
- `_` : Matches the character `_`
- `([^_]+)` : Second capturing group

  - `[^_]+` : Matches any character not present in the list `[_]` one or more times
- `$` : Asserts position at the end of line

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/K6gxuS/1)

Comment: Thanks. what if the column names are such as: abc_rte_pi1_log       xyz_pnct_pi2_log   and I need them as: abc_rte_log_pi1   xyz_pnct_log_pi2

Answer (score 2):

```
mapping = {col:col for col in df.columns}
for colname in df.columns:
    splits = colname.rsplit("_",2)
    if splits[-2] == 'pi':
        newname = "_".join((splits[0], splits[-1], splits[-2]))
        mapping[colname] = newname

df.rename(columns=mapping, inplace=True)
```